# How can i use c# dynamic object in boo (Rhino DSL)?

Tags: c#, dynamic, boo, rhino-dsl

I am using Rhino DSL and when I want to pass a dynamic object into script,
boo compiler throws the Exception below:
**BCE0019: Boo.Lang.Compiler.CompilerError: 'Percent' is not a member of 'object'.**

my boo code:

```
Result = Run().Percent
```

C# Dsl Base code for Run method:

```
dynamic myDynamicObject;
public dynamic Run()
{

   //do somthing

   return myDynamicObject;
}
```

- in Run method I set myDynamicObject to a class that inherits from DynamicObject and override TrySetValue & TryGetValue method

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how exactly 'Percent' is being called, or if Rhino.DSL is configured with ducky Boo as default, but you can try 'casting' as duck, e.g. `(myobject as duck).Percent`. See http://boo.codehaus.org/Duck+Typing for reference.

Comment: thanks, I edit my question and add code to show how exactly 'Percent' is being called

Comment: also I try casting to duck but it doesn't compile too!